# Code 400, Unrecognized field "customer" not marked as ignorable

Tags: java, rest, jax-ws, restkit

My problem:

I`ve built a rest client within my iphone-application with restkit 0.20. 
My RESTService was built with jax-rs including jackson.

There is one class named "Customer", where I hold my customer data.

```
@XmlRootElement                                
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {

private int customer_id;
private String appell;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private Date birthday;
private String street;
private String streetnr;
private String zipcode;
private String place;

public int getCustomer_id() {
    return customer_id;
}

public void setCustomer_id(int customer_id) {
    this.customer_id = customer_id;
}

public String getAppell() {
    return appell;
}

public void setAppell(String appell) {
    this.appell = appell;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public Date getBirthday() {
    return birthday;
}

public void setBirthday(Date birthday) {
    this.birthday = birthday;
}

public String getStreet() {
    return street;
}
public void setStreet(String street) {
    this.street = street;
}
public String getStreetnr() {
    return streetnr;
}
public void setStreetnr(String streetnr) {
    this.streetnr = streetnr;
}
public String getZipcode() {
    return zipcode;
}
public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
    this.zipcode = zipcode;
}
public String getPlace() {
    return place;
}
public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}
```

What can I do? Why there's always this error logged in RestKit:

```
Expected status code in (200-299), got 400" UserInfo=0x956e2f0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Unrecognized field "customer" (Class customer.model.Customer), not marked as ignorable
```

I don't have a field named customer.

Here is my POST method:

```
@POST
@Path("/insert")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response insertCustomer(Customer customer) {
    String result = "Customer inserted " + customer.getLastname();
    customer.createEntity();
    return Response.status(201).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(result).build();
}
```

This is an example of a generated JSON object (Jackson), when a @GET method is called within my ios application.

```
 {
"appell": "Frau",
"birthday": "1991-10-01T00:00:00+01:00",
"customer_id": "3",
"firstname": "Max",
"lastname": "Mustermann",
"place": "München",
"street": "Einsteinweg",
"streetnr": "19",
"zipcode": "81858"
```

}

And this is an example of the JSON object, when my ios application calls the showed @POST method:

```
{"customer":{"streetnr":"19",
 "zipcode":"81829",
 "customer_id":0,
 "place":"München",
 "appell":"Herr",
 "firstname":"Heinrich",
 "birthday":"1991-10-01T00:00:00+01:00",
 "lastname":"Maier",
 "street":"Lehrer-Wirth-Str.19"}}
```

I am a absolute newbie using restkit and jax-rs.

I just added a @GET method for requesting xml format.
Here you can see it:

```
@GET
@Path("/listallcustomers")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public ArrayList<Customer> showAllCustomers() {
    ArrayList<Customer> list = DBAccess.getInstance().getAllCustomers();
    return list;
}
```

and this is the result:

```
<customers>
  <customer>
  <appell>Frau</appell>
  <birthday>1991-10-01T00:00:00+01:00</birthday>
  <customer_id>3</customer_id>
  <firstname>Max</firstname>
  <lastname>MUstermann</lastname>
  <place>München</place>
  <street>Einsteinstr.</street>
  <streetnr>19</streetnr>
  <zipcode>82838</zipcode>
</customer>
  ...
```

My @GET method which creates a JSON object is the following:

```
@GET
@Path("/listall")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ArrayList<Customer> showAllJsonCustomers() {
    ArrayList<Customer> list = DBAccess.getInstance().getAllCustomers();
    return list;
}
```

and this an example of a JSON object it creates:

```
{
"lastname": "Müller",
"customer_id": 6,
"appell": "Herr",
"firstname": "pupsi",
"birthday": "1986-10-16",
"street": "Lehrer-Wirth-Str",
"streetnr": "19",
"zipcode": "81829",
"place": "München"
},
...
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, i don`t generate xml, but i`ve just inserted a method to show you, how it would look. You can find the example in my edited start post.

Comment: Well the error occurs because of how your object is serialized to json. `customer` as the json key and its fields as a json object.

Comment: JAX-RS uses jackson to serialize your object. It uses the name of the class as the key to the json object. If you don't want this, you'll have to write your own serializer. Can you show your `@GET` method?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, sorry i don`t understand (im just a newbie)...
jackson seems to swallow the class name "Customer" while RestKit creates the json object WITH the classname...

Comment: [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) is a framework that JAX-RS uses to transform the object you return in your `@GET` and `@POST` methods to JSON format. Depending on the type of these objects, the json will be different.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, thank you for your reply. I understand what you mean. But i have one last question. How do I get the jsonString? I thought i have to hand over a Customer-Object in my method head (as a parameter)... but could it be, that in my method head it should be just a String jsonString as parameter and just map it to a Customer object?

Comment: To get the json string, you would have to explicitly use Jackson to make it or make it yourself. Google jackson json example and see how that is done.

Comment: i`ve done this with a object mapper yet... but the problem is, that this json string looks so: `{"customer":{"streetnr":"19",
"zipcode":"81829",
"customer_id":0,
"place":"München",
"appell":"Herr",
"firstname":"Django",
"birthday":"1991-1001T00:00:00+01:00",
"lastname":"Maier",
"street":"Lehrer-Wirth-Str.19"}}`

the value customer which stands for the class customer must be erased... there is no attribute "customer" to map...  
I need a json string without the Object in it... beginning just with
 {
  "appell":"Frau",
  ...

Comment: That's just how Jackson works. I don't know a way to go around it. Try doing your own serialization

Comment: yes, like i said. jackson want to map a attribute customer, although there doesn`t exists one. The first attribute in the jsonString `{"customer":{...` is the name of the object ( of class Customer) which is parsed to a JSONString and not an attribute in class Customer... this doesnt make sense to me

Comment: thanks to @SotiriosDelimanolis! solved the problem. went through your comments and had some ideas. first i tried to wrap the json string with help of a wrapper class, but then i researched @restkit and found a way to manipulate the json object. just set keyPath: to nil!